# Changing chapter reference abbreviation

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendix

I have the following example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % lines
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents % Table of contents 

  \chapter{This is a Chapter}
    \section{And this a Section}

  \chapter{Another Chapter}
    \section{And another Section}

  \appendix
  \chapter{This is the Appendix}
    Here 5 useful thing that (probably) you didn't know

  \chapter*{List of Symbols}
    Here a list of symbols
    \begin{table}[ht]
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{cp{0.7\textwidth}}
            \toprule[2pt]
            
            Symbol & Description \\
            
            \midrule
            
            $\mathcal{A}$ & \nth{1} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
            $\mathcal{B}$ & \nth{2} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
            $\mathcal{C}$ & \nth{3} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
            $\mathcal{D}$ & \nth{4} letter of the latin alphabet \\
            
            \bottomrule[2pt]
      \end{tabular}%
      \caption{Description of the symbols}
      \label{table:symbols}
   \end{table}

\end{document}
```

that returns the following table of contents:
[image: table of contents]

and the following list of symbols:
[image: list of symbols]

Problems:

1. Why the List of symbols chapter is not included in the TOC? There is some command/package required to do that?
2. How can I change the caption in the table of symbols so that is not "A.1" but "S.1" (I'd prefer an automatic way, since there are in reality a lot of tables there)
3. How can I remove the "A" in front of "This is the Appendix" just in the TOC

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally starred headings commands are not added to the table of contents. You can try `\chapter*{foo}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{foo}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** To add the unnumbered (starred) chapter to the table of contents, use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{This is the Appendix}
```

**(2)** To remove the chapter number of a chapter in the ToC, starred it and use recipe (1).

```
\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
```

[image: a]

**(3)** To change the numbering style of the tables, you can redefine the counter of the table. It will be applied from this place to all tables.

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S.\arabic{table}} % added <<<<<
```

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % lines
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % Table of contents 

\chapter{This is a Chapter}
\section{And this a Section}

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\section{And another Section}

\appendix
\chapter*{This is the Appendix} %changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{This is the Appendix} % added <<<<<

Here 5 useful thing that (probably) you didn't know

\chapter*{List of Symbols} % changed
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols} % added <<<<<

\renewcommand{\thetable}{S.\arabic{table}} % added <<<<<

Here a list of symbols

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cp{0.7\textwidth}}
        \toprule[2pt]   
        Symbol & Description \\ 
        \midrule    
        $\mathcal{A}$ & \nth{1} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{B}$ & \nth{2} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{C}$ & \nth{3} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{D}$ & \nth{4} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        \bottomrule[2pt]
    \end{tabular}%
\caption{Description of the symbols 1}
\label{table:symbols}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cp{0.7\textwidth}}
        \toprule[2pt]
        Symbol & Description \\
        \midrule
        $\mathcal{A}$ & \nth{1} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{B}$ & \nth{2} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{C}$ & \nth{3} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{D}$ & \nth{4} letter of the latin alphabet \\
        \bottomrule[2pt]
    \end{tabular}%
\caption{Description of the symbols 2}
\label{table:symbolsi}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cp{0.7\textwidth}}
        \toprule[2pt]
        Symbol & Description \\
        \midrule
        $\mathcal{A}$ & \nth{1} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{B}$ & \nth{2} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{C}$ & \nth{3} letter of the latin alphabet \\ 
        $\mathcal{D}$ & \nth{4} letter of the latin alphabet \\
        \bottomrule[2pt]
    \end{tabular}%
\caption{Description of the symbols 3}
\label{table:symbolsii}
\end{table} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!